# Command line tool to analyse disk space based on file types

Tags: windows, networking, command-line-interface, disk-space-utilization, analysis

Basically, I'm looking for something like Windirstat that works well on the command line and is easy to distribute over a network.

I've tried sysinternals du (can't exclude/include file types), diruse (limited like du), cygwin du (too slow). I've also tried all the graphical tools I can find, and none have a command line interface.

Any hidden gem I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I've found [Xinorbis](http://www.freshney.org/xinorbis/). It seems brilliant.

Comment: It looks like it creates some nice data\good charts (although pie charts are useless IMO, the others are good) and is worth trying out to see what it actually does with a nice big volume of messy data, and whether performance is decent. Thanks for the pointer..

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing/able to take Unix tools to your Windows machine (which I guess you are, since you're using du already), you could try using findutils from cygwin in a bash script:

```
for filetype in doc xls jpg mov; do
  combined=0
  find /cygdrive/c -name "*.$filetype" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -k | \
    (while read; do
      current=$(echo $REPLY | awk '{print $1}'
      combined=$(( $combined + $current ))
    done)
    echo "$filetype files use $combined KiB on C:"
done
```

NB - this is roughly what I'd do; it's not tested.

Surely, this could be done more efficiently if you would like to do this for every type of file in the system. For single types, it probably wouldn't get much better with dedicated tools since this should be so IO-bound.

Comment: I'm a bit weary of trying another cygwin based tool for performance reasons